# Best way to extra array of strings with regular expressions this single string

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a data table converted from JSON where one of the columns has rows that look like this that are of character class:

```
"[{u'className': u'Sticker', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'mYz1ietNEt'}, {u'className': u'Sticker', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'FVn0hE5Zar'}, {u'className': u'Sticker', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'ZxUTYYCunL'}]"
```

What I really want is a vector of the objectId's, so ideally from the above I would get:

```
['mYz1ietNEt', 'FVn0hE5Zar', 'ZxUTYYCunL']
```

What's the best way to get there? Or how do I get there at all? For a single string, `test`, here's what I've tried:

```
test1 = strsplit(test, split = "}, ")
test1 = test1[[1]]
```

That's fine, but I can't seem to find a way to get rid of the left bracket `{` let alone the other portions of the string that are undesirable.

```
> test2 = strsplit(test1, "{")
Error in strsplit(test1, "{") : 
  invalid regular expression '{', reason 'Missing '}''
> test2 = strsplit(test1, "\{")
Error: '\{' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\{"
> test2 = strsplit(test1, u"{")
Error: unexpected string constant in "test2 = strsplit(test1, u"{""
> test2 = strsplit(test1, r"{")
Error: unexpected string constant in "test2 = strsplit(test1, r"{""
```

Ideally I could find some regex expression that could extract all of the `objectId` fields in one fell swoop into a vector. Is there something like this?

Comment: You need to escape it with `'\\{'` or `'[{]'`

Comment: `stringr::str_extract_all(test1, "(?<=objectId':\\su')(.*?)(?=')")` works, but it could prob be shortened with tweaks.

Comment: @PierreLafortune: I had the same solution on mind. And I guess that's only approach to find something surrounded by _somethings_.

Comment: @PierreLafortune That's just perfect and it's vectorized, which is extra awesome. Can you put this in an answer so I can check it off?

Comment: I hesitate because I could not get the capture group to work correctly. Instead I couched the match between two lookarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the identified strings with a regular expression pattern:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(test1, "(?<=objectId':\\su')(.*?)(?=')")[[1]]
[1] "mYz1ietNEt" "FVn0hE5Zar" "ZxUTYYCunL"
```